# Как изменить имя файла в цикле с++

Tags: c++

Прошу подсказать как можно создавать новое имя для файла в цикле?

Comment: Fursenko Думаю, что точно также, как и без хоровода вокруг елочки.:)

Comment: Да как угодно можно его создавать.

Comment: Есть файл например fs.txt следующий должен иметь другое имя, например fs1.txt?

Comment: @AleksandrFursenko ну вот вы сами и ответили на свой вопрос как можно создавать имя файла. Берите и реализовывайте озвученный вами алгоритм на нужном языке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

мой пример посмотрите к примеру. результат работы этой программы три новых файла в корне диска Ц (под виндовс писал)...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    ofstream file; // сам файл
    char filename[2]; // временный буфер
    string path; // сюда мы будем ложить новые имена

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){ // цикл который будет создовать новые имена (и создаст новые файлы с новым именем
        itoa(i, filename, 10); // преоброзовать в текстовый символ
        path = "C:\\file"; // часть имени файла (оно будет постоянным)
        path += filename; // собираем путь и имя для нового файла
        file.open(path.c_str()); // создать новый файл с новым именем
        file.close(); // обязательно закрываем
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А можно вместо 3-х строк (начиная с itoa()) использовать один вызов функции [snprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) / При желании можно уйти от ofstream и несколько более эффективно делать файл одной строкой на низком уровне `close(open(path, ....))`

Comment: даже затрудняюсь с ответом я этой функцией не умею пользоваться и не знал что функция close() может принимать параметры

Comment: Так почитайте man-ы. Вы же программист, стыдно не знать основ POSIX.

Comment: да я как бы на оборот уйти от сишного стиля кодирования хочу. я даже в этом коде не хотел бы использовать настоящий массив и функцию itoa, потому что вместо этого в с++ есть функция to_string(), но она у меня не работает потому что у меня кривой компилятор. вот и пришлось так выкручиваться )

Comment: Дело Ваше. IMHO надо по возможности использовать лучшие (в широком смысле (здесь и сейчас обсуждать что стоит за этими словами мы, конечно же, не будем)) средства, независимо от их "происхождения".

Comment: согласен с вами